# Unable To Display Desired Output

Tags: java, android, user-interface

I'm having trouble on displaying an output on my interface.

My program should be able to display respective outputs upon inputting some parameters. If no parameters were entered, it shall display "No results" which is what I have implemented.

However, even with parameters entered . It still displays "No results" instead of the answer according to formula given.

My code is as follow:

```
public class FreeSpaceActivity extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {

    DecimalFormat disp_W = new DecimalFormat("0.000E0");
    DecimalFormat disp_dBm = new DecimalFormat("0.000");

    EditText tPowerEdit = null;
    EditText tGainEdit = null;
    EditText rGainEdit = null;
    EditText freqEdit = null;
    EditText distanceEdit = null;
    EditText lightEdit = null;
    Button calButton = null;
    Button graphButton = null;
    Button clearButton = null;
    Button plotButton = null;

    EditText radEdit = null;//testing

    private ScrollView llLayout;
    private FragmentActivity faActivity;
    //private Switch switch1;
    // Changes here
    private double mResult = 0;
    private Switch mSelectUnit;
    private TextView mTextFreeSpaces;
    private boolean mIsCalculated;// flag to show the result only when you click on calculate button
    private boolean flag;


    //@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(null);

        faActivity = (FragmentActivity) this.getActivity();
        llLayout = (ScrollView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_free_space, container, false);

        tPowerEdit = (EditText)llLayout.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        tGainEdit = (EditText)llLayout.findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        rGainEdit = (EditText)llLayout.findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        freqEdit = (EditText)llLayout.findViewById(R.id.editText4);
        distanceEdit = (EditText)llLayout.findViewById(R.id.editText7);
        lightEdit = (EditText)llLayout.findViewById(R.id.editText8);
        calButton = (Button)llLayout.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        calButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        graphButton = (Button)llLayout.findViewById(R.id.button2);
        graphButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        clearButton = (Button)llLayout.findViewById(R.id.button3);
        clearButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        plotButton =(Button)llLayout.findViewById(R.id.plot_button);
        plotButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        radEdit = (EditText)llLayout.findViewById(R.id.editText28);//testing

        // Changes here
        mTextFreeSpaces = (TextView) llLayout.findViewById(R.id.textFreeSpaces);

        mSelectUnit =(Switch)llLayout.findViewById(R.id.switch1);
        mSelectUnit.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                updateFreeSpacesText(isChecked);
            }
        });
        return llLayout;
    }

    /*private ActionBar getSupportActionBar() {
        return null;
    }*/

    private void updateFreeSpacesText(boolean isSwitcherChecked) {
        if(mIsCalculated && flag==true){
            if(isSwitcherChecked){
                double dBm=10 * Math.log10(mResult* 1000);
                mTextFreeSpaces.setText(disp_dBm.format(dBm));//display dbm
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"Unit Chosen is dBm", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                double W=mResult;
                mTextFreeSpaces.setText(disp_W.format(W));//display W
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"Unit Chosen is W", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String tPowerStr = tPowerEdit.getText().toString();
        String tGainStr = tGainEdit.getText().toString();
        String rGainStr = rGainEdit.getText().toString();
        String freqStr = freqEdit.getText().toString();
        String distanceStr = distanceEdit.getText().toString();
        String lightStr = lightEdit.getText().toString();
        double tPower = Double.parseDouble(!tPowerStr.isEmpty() ? tPowerStr : "0");
        double tGain = Double.parseDouble(!tGainStr.isEmpty() ? tGainStr : "0");
        double rGain = Double.parseDouble(!rGainStr.isEmpty() ? rGainStr : "0");
        double freq = Double.parseDouble(!freqStr.isEmpty() ? freqStr : "0");
        double distance = Double.parseDouble(!distanceStr.isEmpty() ? distanceStr : "1");
        double light = Double.parseDouble(!lightStr.isEmpty() ? lightStr : "1");

        String radStr = radEdit.getText().toString();//testing
        double radius = Double.parseDouble(!radStr.isEmpty() ? radStr : "0");//testing


        if (v == calButton) {
            if(mResult!=0) {
                double lamda = 300000000 / freq;

                mResult = tPower * tGain * rGain * Math.pow(lamda / (4 * Math.PI * distance), 2) / light / 100;
                mIsCalculated = true;
                flag = true;
                updateFreeSpacesText(mSelectUnit.isChecked());
            }
            else
                mTextFreeSpaces.setText("No results");


        }
        else if (v == graphButton) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), GraphActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("model", "freeSpace");
            intent.putExtra("tp", tPower);
            intent.putExtra("tg", tGain);
            intent.putExtra("rg", rGain);
            intent.putExtra("f", freq);
            intent.putExtra("l", light);
            this.startActivity(intent);
        } else if (v == clearButton) {
            flag=false;
            double lamda = 300000000 / freq;

            ((EditText) llLayout.findViewById(R.id.editText1)).setText(null);
            ((EditText) llLayout.findViewById(R.id.editText2)).setText(null);
            ((EditText) llLayout.findViewById(R.id.editText3)).setText(null);
            ((EditText) llLayout.findViewById(R.id.editText4)).setText(null);
            ((EditText) llLayout.findViewById(R.id.editText7)).setText(null);
            ((EditText) llLayout.findViewById(R.id.editText8)).setText(null);
            ((EditText) llLayout.findViewById(R.id.editText28)).setText(null);
            ((TextView) llLayout.findViewById(R.id.textFreeSpaces)).setText(null);
            //((TextView) llLayout.findViewById(R.id.textFreeSpacePrd)).setText("");
            //mIsCalculated = true;
            //updateFreeSpacesText(mSelectUnit.isChecked());
            //mResult=tPower * tGain * rGain * Math.pow(lamda / (4 * Math.PI * distance), 2) / light / 100;
            //mTextFreeSpaces.setText("");


        } else if (v == plotButton) {
            //double radius = Double.parseDouble(radius.getText().toString());
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MapActivity.class);
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            //b.putDouble("radius", result);
            intent.putExtras(b);
            this.startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

My interface:

[image]

Comment: Actually, you set "no results" if mResults is equal to 0. You by default initiliaze it to 0, and I don't see you change it's value anywhere.

Comment: @Stultuske, initially it would display "NaN" instead because according to the formula, all variables has been initialized to 0 which would result in math error.

Comment: no. if(mResult!=0) {/* your code here */ } else setText("No result");
and mResult equals 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [Stultuske](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2636929/stultuske) is right but my Reputation is to low to comment.

I would prefer that you change the statement of the IF-Clause

```
        if (v == calButton) {
        if(mResult!=0) {
            .
            .
            .
        }
        else
            mTextFreeSpaces.setText("No results");
```

otherway you're running in the else-branch everytime because your variable mResult is still 0 and hasn't changed.

Maybe you can retreive if the Edittexts are not empty like

```
            if(tPowerStr.matches("") && The other Edittexts) {
                .
                .
                .
            }
            else
                mTextFreeSpaces.setText("No results");
```

EDIT:
By the way I'm interested in your App because I'm a directional radio and satellite communication engineer.

Comment: Hi, this is my project. I'm working on a RFcalculator and this is one of the module

Comment: If you were free, could you spend some time? I'm currently new to RF developments and was exposed to 2 propagation modules only in my course which is Free Space Loss & Two Ray. However, I'm too looking forward into implementing more models such as HATA. Would be glad if I can get some advices from you :-)

Comment: First of all, does your programm now work properly? Is the problem solved? After that we can talk about RF. :)

Comment: What did you mean by my program work properly? As for now, everything is ok in my own opinion and the problem I posted here has too been resolved. Thanks to all of you